# Why can't I share my Google Docs presentation outside of my college network?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace

I am a student at Smith College trying to make a Google Docs presentation visible to anyone in the world with a link.

However, the options that surface when I click Share only let me share within Smith College. This document is also shared with some other students at Smith College.

[image: The options that surface when I click Share only let me share within Smith College.]

Why can't I share this presentation with the rest of the world?

In fact, I can't even publish it on the web to everyone.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's because you don't have permissions to do so. The administrator of the Google Apps account has disabled this ability. There is a setting in the admin that scopes out the permissions and share abilities.

They've [selected the option that restricts other users](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60781) from being able to see or edit the document unless they are within the organisation, in this case, the school.

> Users **cannot share** documents outside this organization

In order to be able to share from Google Docs, you will need to have the administrator's account change the settings permission to allow you to do so.

Answer (score 5):

I think being it a college policy if that is something that you should not share with world or your friends outside you should not try to do that but in another case what you can do is upload that presentation on your personal gmail account and from there you can make it public or share with friends.

Answer (score -1):

In case you have admin rights, you'll have to wait a couple of hours to get it working. This article talks about that. So you need a bit of patience, and wait.

http://techblog.willshouse.com/2012/02/01/google-docs-share-outside-my-organization-solved/