# Google Apps, how to publish to the web outside my organization?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I share my Google Docs presentation outside of my college network?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/27828/why-cant-i-share-my-google-docs-presentation-outside-of-my-college-network)

I want to "publish to the web" a spreadsheet so a person outside my organization (Google Apps for Business) can see it (and can't edit it), but I can't fin the way, every document I publish is accessible for people from my organization. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To publish any of your docs, follow the [steps outlined in the Google Docs documentation](http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37579).

Note that your administrator can prevent published docs from being shared outside of your domain. If you'd like to change this setting, you'll need to contact your administrator directly.